# Group a batch of variables "abcd..." into two batches with all possible combinations. (recursion)

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, recursion, combinations

I have two groups (A) and (B) and a amount of variables abcde... (>2) to sort into the groups, that at least one variable is in group (A) and one is in group (B). The programm should print out all combinations. The order of the output is not important.

For 3 variables "abc" The result should be:

```
A  | B
-------
ac | b
ab | c
bc | a
a  | bc
b  | ac
c  | ab
```

The programm I wrote is:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

string gencombinations(string , string );
string removeCharsFromString( string , string);

int main(){
    string result;
    string a = "";
    string b = "";
    string batch = "abc";

    a = batch;

    cout << "batch \ta = {"; cout << a; cout << "},\t batch b = {"; cout << b; cout << "}\t"; cout << endl;
    result = gencombinations(a, b);
    //cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}

string gencombinations(string a, string b){

    string _tmp;
    string _tmp2;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {

        _tmp = a.at(i+1);
        b = _tmp+b;

        cout << "remove \t {"; cout << _tmp; cout << "},\t\t from a = {"; cout << a; cout << "}\t"; cout << endl;
        a= removeCharsFromString( a, _tmp );
        cout << "batch \ta = {"; cout << a; cout << "},\t batch b = {"; cout << b; cout << "}\t"; cout << endl;

        if(a.size() > 1)
            _tmp2 = gencombinations(a, b);
        if(_tmp2 != "") return _tmp2;

        b = removeCharsFromString( b, _tmp );

    }

    return _tmp2;
}

string removeCharsFromString( string str, string charsToRemove ) {

    for (int i = 0; i < charsToRemove.length(); ++i ) {
        //cout << "charsToRemove  = {"; cout << charsToRemove.at(i); cout << "},\t From String = {"; cout << str; cout << "}\t"; cout << endl;
        std::string::size_type s = str.find(charsToRemove.at(i));
        if (s != std::string::npos)
            str.erase(i+1, 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Which gives the output:

```
batch   a = {abc},       batch b = {}
remove   {b},            from a = {abc}
batch   a = {ac},        batch b = {b}
remove   {c},            from a = {ac}
batch   a = {a},         batch b = {cb}
```

and breaks. (That there is no Variable in batch B in the beginning is no problem).

Getting rid of `out_of_range` (answer from @Paul) I get:

```
string gencombinations(string a, string b){

    string _tmp;
    string _tmp2;
    string _resul;


    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {
        _tmp = a.at(i);

        b = _tmp+b;

        if(a.size() > 1)
            a= removeCharsFromString( a, _tmp );

        cout << "batch \ta = {"; cout << a; cout << "},\t batch b = {"; cout << b; cout << "}\t"; cout << endl;

        if(a.size() > 1){
            cout << "recursion" << endl;
            _tmp2 = gencombinations(a, b);
        }

        if(_tmp2 != "") {
            return _tmp2;
            cout << "_tmp2 is empty" << endl;
        }

        b = removeCharsFromString( b, _tmp );
        a = _tmp;
    }
    return _tmp2;
}

string removeCharsFromString( string str, string charsToRemove ){
    for (int i = 0; i < charsToRemove.length(); ++i ) {
        std::string::size_type s = str.find(charsToRemove.at(i));
        if (s != std::string::npos)
            str.erase(i, 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

With the output:

```
batch   a = {bcd},       batch b = {a}
recursion
batch   a = {cd},        batch b = {ba}
recursion
batch   a = {d},         batch b = {cba}
```

How to get the recursion right?

Comment: `How to get the recoursion right?` Debugging, paper and pencil. You have no idea how powerful these 3 are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {
      _tmp = a.at(i+1);
```

contains a logic mistake. Strings are 0-based in c++, like any other type of array or vector. At some point the code tries to read the first char after the end of the string from the array. At that point the program will throw an `out_of_range`-exception (just wrap that line with a try-catch to watch it yourself).

As for your code: I don't quite understand the purpose of `tmp2`. There's no line in the code where `tmp2` is explicitly created, so it's always "", independent of the input.

But there are actually simpler solutions to this than moving each character at an arbitrary time from `a` to `b`, which will always produce duplicates aswell. Instead you could use one of these simplifications:

### Using a permutation of 0s and 1s

Use a permutation of 0s and 1s, where 0 means put the char in `a` and 1 means put the char in `b`:

```
void gencombinations(string allchars){
    for(unsigned int permute = 0 ; permute < (1 << allchars.size()) ; permute++){
        string a, b;

        for(unsigned int bit = 0 ; bit < allchars.size() ; bit++)
            if(permute & (1 << bit))
                a += allchars[bit];
            else
                b += allchars[bit];

        cout << "batch: a = {" + a + "}, b: {" + b + "}" << endl;
    }
}
```

Note that this solution only works for input-strings of a specific size. The bitcount of `permute` determines the maximum-length of the input-string. E.g. datatypes with 32 bits would allow input-strings of a maximum-length of 32. For input-alphabets that are larger than 64, a workaround to this basic solution is required.

### Using recursive calls and distribution

Use recursive method-calls and fork, where one call adds the char to `a` and one to `b`:

```
gencombinations(string chars , string a , string b){
    if(chars.size()){
        char c = chars[0];
        chars.erase(0 , 1);

        gencombinations(chars , a + c , b);
        gencombinations(chars , a , b + c);
    }else
        cout << "batch: a = {" + a + "}, b = {" + b + "}";
}
```

Comment: I changed the code to get rid of `out_of_range` but the mistake in the recoursion is still there.

Comment: @kimliv I've edited my answer with a few notes and suggestions. I couldn't find the mistake though. I'll keep working on that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to remove anything. Just keep building your group strings `a` and `b` from the batch until the batch has been exausted.

Of course, you must consider two cases for each letter from the batch: It goes either into group A or into group B. When you recurse, you must fork your recursion for each of these cases. You must also remove the current letter from the batch, but that is easy, because it is the first letter in the string:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void combo(string batch, string a, string b)
{
    if (batch.size() == 0) {
        if (a.size() && b.size()) {
            cout << a << " :: " << b << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        combo(batch.substr(1), a + batch[0], b);
        combo(batch.substr(1), a, b + batch[0]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    combo("abc", "", "");

    return 0;
}
```

This solution just prints the strings at the bottom level of the recursion. You could as well append them to a string stream or string.